# Google Analytics events not recording

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to get an event when I'm pressing a button but I can't see any clue of my activity on my Google Analytics page. I followed the Google Analytics tutorial in this page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Following that instructions I've created a button with the id "button":

```
<a href="https://cellkulture.typeform.com/to/ThBzIr" class="btn btn-phenol btn-lg btn-block typeform-share invite" style="margin-bottom:30px; margin-top:20px;" data-mode="1" target="_blank" id="signUpForm">Request an Invite to the Beta</a>
```

yes I know i need to loose the inline styling but this is a work in progress

then I have included in the head of the document the main Google Analytics call to connect my page to the right database (I've changed UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'myname.com with my current settings)

```
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(     
    {(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
    Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o) 
    [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})
    (window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'myname.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

and lastly I paste that code on the bottom of the page that should track the event:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var downloadLink = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
addListener(downloadLink, 'click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'signup');
});

function addListener(element, type, callback) {
 if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
 else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
}
</script>
```

This is so close to googles example I can't understand why I dont see the event tracking in google analytics. I am using the realtime view to look at this in case that makes any difference?

Comment: Can you check in your browser's network inspector if a request is being sent to Google?

Comment: Try the GA Debug chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Comment: Also, if you're using the async tracking code it should be within the `body` tag I believe

Comment: Adam the suggestion of the debug extension was genius! Simple error corrected. I can't say what it was as it was soooo very stupid. Thanks for your help!